# angular use filter with different input

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a simple list of people with a name and a first name and I would like to be able to perform a filter when creates a search for a field or the other or both

[image]

Html is as follows :

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>
                <input [(ngModel)]="searchText.nom" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom">
              </th>
              <th>
                <input [(ngModel)]="searchText.prenom" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Prénom">
              </th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let defunt of defunts | filterPersonne : searchText">
              <td>{{defunt.nom}}</td>
              <td>{{defunt.prenom}}</td>
          </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

and I have written this filter:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DefuntSearch } from '../models/DefuntSearch';
import { Defunt } from '../models/Defunt';
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterPersonne'
})
export class FilterDefuntPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: Array<Personne>, searchText: Search):  Array<Personne> {
      items = searchText.nom ? items.filter(t => t.nom.includes(searchText.nom)) : items;
      items = searchText.prenom ? items.filter(t => t.nom.includes(searchText.prenom)) : items;
      return items;
   }
}
```

my class :

```
export class Search {
  constructor(
    public nom?: string,
    public prenom?: string,
  ) {

  }
}
```

when I type a string for searchText, the filter works but when searchText is object the filter does not call on searchText.nom or searchText.prenom change.
can you help me?

tanks your

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alternatively use as

```
<tr *ngFor="let defunt of defunts | filterPersonne : 
                             { nom:searchText.nom, prenom:searchText.prenom }">
```